# In the analogy of turning car wheels related to bending of light while entering glass through air, does that imply that two photons are "connected"?

Tags: refraction

There's a famous analogy that explains the bending of light when it enters glass from air.

[image]

But doesn't that imply that two photons, represented by the adjacent wheels of the car, are connected by an axel? How could two distinct photons be connected like that, and what is the axel that connects them?

Comment: The wheels do not represent two photons. Honestly... analogies are not perfect. I would probably not even put this one among the good ones, either.

Comment: @CuriousOne Then what do the wheels actually represent and what does the axel? Is axel something that actually breaks the analogy?

Comment: One could think of the axle representing wavefronts, but in all honestly, I would not use this analogy to teach refraction. I don't think it helps.

Comment: This is a poor analogy.  "Famous"?  In 40 years of doing physics I've never seen it.  In addition to the complaints above, there's this:  normally you stand behind a lawnmower and push it, controlling where you want it to go.  To understand the analogy, you must understand *in advance* what it is trying to communicate.

Comment: A similar but better analogy can be found in [this document](http://mremrich.com/physics12/physics12/Attachments/a_Student_Text/P12SB461.pdf), on the top of p. 463 (the third page of the pdf).   I thought for sure there would be a youtube video of this demonstration, or at least a better picture of it, but it's all I could find in a quick search.